# How to design a task queue with mutually exclusive but independently concurrent methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I was asked a concurrency question in a job interview, that eventually boiled down to the following requirements. I was able to achieve #2 through #4 simply by using mutual exclusion, but not #1.

> Design a task queue with the following methods:
>
> `public void registerCallback(Runnable task)`
>
> `public void eventFired()`
>
> 1. Multiple threads should be able to put tasks on the queue, possibly concurrently.
> 2. `eventFired` should only be invoked once.
> 3. If `eventFired` has been previously invoked, any later invocation of either methods should throw an exception.
> 4. If `eventFired` is invoked while `registerCallback` is executing, delay firing the event until a later time.
> 5. If `registerCallback` is invoked while `eventFired` is executing, throw  an exception.

`ReentrantReadWriteLock` seems promising, because `registerCallback` can acquire the read lock, and `eventFired` the write lock, but that doesn't solve a race condition where `registerCallback` is invoked, and then `eventFired`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> `ReentrantReadWriteLock` seems promising, because `registerCallback` can acquire the read lock, and `eventFired` the write lock, but that doesn't solve a race condition where `registerCallback` is invoked, and then `eventFired`.

Registering a callback, in other words, modifying a data structure, while holding a read lock, is never a good idea. You’d need another thread safe construct for the storage of the callbacks and complicate the code unnecessarily.

The operation of registering a callback, like storing a reference into some collection or instantiating whatever kind of node object, is trivial enough to allow using an ordinary mutual exclusive lock, as it is not held for long.

Whether you use `synchronized`, a `Lock`, or a state supporting atomic updates, in either case, the race condition does not exist, as there can’t be an overlap of `registerCallback` or `eventFired`. All of these approaches bring an order into these operations, when used correctly. So every `registerCallback` is either, before the first `eventFired` or after it.

Implementing this can be straight-forward:

```
public class JobQueue {
    private List<Runnable> callbacks = new ArrayList<>();

    public synchronized void registerCallback(Runnable task) {
        if(callbacks == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Event already fired");
        }
        callbacks.add(Objects.requireNonNull(task));
    }
    public void eventFired() {
        List<Runnable> list;
        synchronized(this) {
            list = callbacks;
            callbacks = null;
        }
        if(list == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can only fire once");
        }
        for(Runnable r: list) r.run();
    }
}
```

The code executed within the `synchronized` blocks is so short, that contention will be irrelevant for most practical use cases. Implementing the same with a `Lock` would be straight-forward, but there won’t be any advantage. In fact, JVM specific optimizations may render the `synchronized` based solution more efficient.

For completeness, here an atomic update based solution:

```
public class JobQueue {
    private static final Runnable DONE = () -> {};

    private final AtomicReference<Runnable> pending = new AtomicReference<>();

    public void registerCallback(Runnable task) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(task);
        for(;;) {
            Runnable previous = pending.get();
            if(previous == DONE) throw new IllegalStateException("Event already fired");
            if(pending.compareAndSet(previous, sequence(previous, task))) return;
        }
    }

    public void eventFired() {
        Runnable previous = pending.getAndSet(DONE);
        if(previous == DONE) throw new IllegalStateException("Can only fire once");
        if(previous != null) previous.run();
    }

    static Runnable sequence(Runnable a, Runnable b) {
        return a == null? b: () -> { a.run(); b.run(); };
    }
}
```

Actually, the executions of multiple `registerCallback` and/or `eventFired` invocations may overlap, but in that case, only one can perform the critical atomic update successfully. This brings an order into the operations, making at most one `eventFired` invocation successful and categorizing all `registerCallback` invocations as made *before* or *after* that.